# How to refer to the value of the selected radio button

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, jspx

I need your help in getting the value of the selected radio button. My jsp file has the below code:

```
       <h:selectOneRadio label="Requests" value="#{user.a_request}" layout="pageDirection">
      <td width="50%"><f:selectItem itemLabel="Forward Request to A" itemValue="A"/></td>
      <td width="50%"><f:selectItem itemLabel="Forward Request to B" itemValue="B"/></td>
    </h:selectOneRadio>
```

Any my java bean has:

```
package test;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import java.util.Map;


@ManagedBean(name="user")
@SessionScoped

public class com implements Serializable{

    @SuppressWarnings("compatibility:-364909745519439457")
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7134492943336358840L;

    String a_request;
    String b_request;

    public String geta_request() {
                    return a_request;
            }

            public void seta_request(String a_request) {
                    this.a_request = a_request;
            }


    public String getb_request() {
                    return b_request;
            }

            public void setb_request(String b_request) {
                    this.b_request = b_request;
            }     


}
```

in the value of the radio button "{#user.a_request}", it is producing an error that the reference "user" is not found. So how to solve this issue.

Thanks

Comment: Classname lower case?  And are your getters and setters correctly capitalized?

Comment: Still the issue is the same

Answer (score 0):

Your java class should have

```
private String request;
```

with getter and setter.

Comment: Yes, `h:selectOneRadio` will be used for setup value.